# How can I compute only current instance disks

Tags: scripting, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, shell-scripting, gcloud

I need some help with Google cloud. I need a shell script for creating a current instance snapshot. I have researched and found some shell script which can create snapshots for all project instances, but I don't want to give access to another instances. Please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gcloud command ["gcloud compute disks snapshot [disk_name]"](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/snapshot) to get a snapshot of a specific disk instead of all disks in a project.